# retrieve artifact with maven timestamp from artifactory

Tags: artifactory

Is there a way to retrieve an artifact with the maven timestamp as it was originally uploaded by maven?

from jenkins logs:

```
Uploading: http://artifactory.foo/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/foo/foo-web-service/1.16.0-SNAPSHOT/foo-web-service-1.16.0-20160504.182015-2.tar.gz
```

Results from artifactory REST api:

```
$ curl -X GET 'http://artifactory.foo/artifactory/api/search/gavc?g=com.foo&a=foo-web-service&v=1.16.0-SNAPSHOT&c=*&repos=libs-snapshot-local'
{
  "results" : [ {
    "uri" : "http://artifactory.foo/artifactory/api/storage/libs-snapshot-local/com/foo/foo-web-service/1.16.0-SNAPSHOT/foo-web-service-1.16.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar"
  }, {
    "uri" : "http://artifactory.foo/artifactory/api/storage/libs-snapshot-local/com/foo/foo-web-service/1.16.0-SNAPSHOT/foo-web-service-1.16.0-SNAPSHOT.pom"
  }, {
    "uri" : "http://artifactory.foo/artifactory/api/storage/libs-snapshot-local/com/foo/foo-web-service/1.16.0-SNAPSHOT/foo-web-service-1.16.0-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz"
  }, {
    "uri" : "http://artifactory.foo/artifactory/api/storage/libs-snapshot-local/com/foo/foo-web-service/1.16.0-SNAPSHOT/foo-web-service-1.16.0-SNAPSHOT.war"
  } ]
}
```

I'd like to get the the same name as it was uploaded to via a wget or equivalent...

What I want to acheive:

- jenkins uploads foo-web-service-1.16.0-20160504.182015-2.tar.gz to libs-snapshot-local
- query REST api to get latest artifact link that includes the timestamps in the name with parameters a=foo-web-service&version=1.16.0&...
- wget $artifact_link_with_timestamp

What I currently acheive that does not satisfy my need:

- jenkins uploads foo-web-service-1.16.0-20160504.182015-2.tar.gz to libs-snapshot-local
- query REST api via gavc search with parameters a=foo-web-service&version=1.16.0&...
- wget $artifact_link

*Conclusion* as stated in the accepted answer, the problem was in the artifactory config itself. To achieve what I wanted, I needed the snapshots to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your repository is configured to use unique snapshots (or to use client snapshot policy and you use Maven 3 and up), you can always use the Maven timestamp as a version. Replacing it with `-SNAPSHOT` is a "runtime" trick to make the resolution easier.

If your repository is configured to use non-unique snapshots, the files are actually stored with `-SNAPSHOT` instead of version and override previous snapshots (**don't do that**).

Comment: how would I retrieve the timesptamped version of the artifact with an api call, if I don't have the timestamp in hand at the moment of querying the api?

Comment: Use the [Folder Info](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FolderInfo) REST API command.

Comment: after looking at folder info I don't see how this could help. I am under the impression that my question was not clear enough. I added my expectations/use case in the question. thanks

Comment: here's a snippet of folder info output: `{
            "folder": false,
            "uri": "/multi1-2.24-20130116.153800-2.pom"
        }`. As you can see, the timestamp is there. Check the snapshot policy again.

Comment: so I guess AF config is bad if wha tI get is this: `"children" : [ {
    "uri" : "/maven-metadata.xml",
    "folder" : false
  }, {
    "uri" : "/redeem-web-service-1.16.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar",
    "folder" : false
  }, ...` ?

Comment: Ok I just spotted the config for unique VS nonunique... I will have to investigate what are the potential drawbacks of changing to unique. Thanks for the tip

Comment: The obvious drawback is the storage side, you're going to keep the snapshots. Set up snapshot retention policy to something reasonable (like under 10), and then there are no drawbacks. BTW, please vote and accept.

Comment: thanks for helping and coming back with answers even if I was not understanding what you ment at first!